# curl - How to set Content-Length header at command line?

Tags: curl, command-line

Im using the curl command line tool. I do something like

`curl -XPUT "https://example.org?p1=value1&p2=value2"  -H"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

The server replies with

`HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required`

The solution is usually to set the appropriate `Content-Length` header.

**But what is the Content-Length in this case and how to set it with curl?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default `curl` sets appropriate `Content-Length` header for you when data is provided with `-d` parameter. In your case the server seems to wait for some data in the body. But for some reason you decided to pass the data in the url.

**1.** Simple Solution

Add `-d""` to the command. This will cause curl to set the appropriate length to 0. You could also set the appropriate header to `-H"Content-Length:0"`

**2.** Why transport data as query parameters?

Try instead:
`curl -XPUT -d'p1=value1\np2=value2' https://example.org`

Comment: Did you litteraly asked a question and answered to yourself in under a minute ?

Comment: I was writing the question but found the solution during writing. So I posted the answer together with question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: fair enough, that could help other people then ! :)

Comment: It is also for me. Next time I will look it up again on SO. :-)

Answer (score -6):

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080 -d "Content-Length: 0"
```

Comment: No, Content-Length is a header, not data.

Comment: Always try to explain your answers :).
Or system throws it to "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." section.